# how to remove xsi:type information from gSoap message?

Tags: c++, c, web-services, gsoap

I am woking on windows platform, gSoap is working fine but it integrates complex type defination in the soap message.

How to remove these complex type definition from soap message

> xsi:type="ns4:MYServerRequestDto"
>
> xsi:type="ns4:MySettingDto"

**how to regenerate gsoap files so it will not include type information?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MYServer.Utils" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:wsc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:Register>
      <ns1:request xsi:type="ns4:MYServerRequestDto">
        <ns4:SerialNumber>2</ns4:SerialNumber>
        <ns4:MySetting xsi:type="ns4:MySettingDto">
          <ns4:AVersion>2</ns4:AVersion>
          <ns4:BVersion>2</ns4:BVersion>
         </ns4:MYSetting>
        <ns4:IPAddress>192.168.1.199</ns4:IPAddress>
       </ns1:request>
    </ns1:Register>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using proxy generated by gSOAP tools, then you need to set output mode of the proxy with **SOAP_XML_NOTYPE** flag.

It can be done in two ways:

1. In one place in the init function of the proxy itself, but then every time proxy is generated it will be overwritten.

   ```
   void nsTestBindingProxy::nsTestBindingProxy_init(soap_mode imode, soap_mode omode) 
   {
       omode |= SOAP_XML_NOTYPE; //removes xsi:type
       soap_imode(this->soap, imode);
       soap_omode(this->soap, omode);
       soap_endpoint = NULL;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. After every initialization of the proxy in code by calling soap_omode function

   ```
   nsTestBindingProxy proxy();
   soap_omode(proxy.soap, proxy.soap->omode | SOAP_XML_NOTYPE);
   ```